# Change Drush memory_limit on shared host

Tags: 7, drush

I've got problem using drush on shared host.

`drush status` shows:

```
   Drush version          :  8.0-dev
```

and when I run:

```
   drush php-eval "phpinfo()" | grep memory
```

It reporsts:

```
   memory_limit => 1024M => 1024M
```

Which is quite big

But whenever I run `drush cc all` (this is D7 site) it  with:

```
   Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 61341696) (tried to allocate 79 bytes) in .../public_html/includes/registry.inc on line 41
```

I created `drush.ini` file in `.drush` directory and whatever I put there is reported by drush and `drush status` shows fail as loaded but memory limit does not go away.

Is it possible this error to come from drush version or what else could I ask hosting provider to change or check?

**Edit:** 
When I add `drush.ini` file  in `.drush` directory with following in it:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

and `drush status`

```
PHP executable         :  /usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli   
 PHP configuration      :  /usr/local/php56/lib/php.ini   
                           /home/tennist/.drush/drush.ini 
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                          
 Drush script           :  /chroot/drush/drush.php        
 Drush version          :  8.0-dev                        
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                           
 Drush configuration    :                                 
 Drush alias files      :
```

In /usr/local/php56/lib/php.ini  memory_limit = 1024M

In /home/tesnnist/.drush/drush.ini memory_limit = 256M

the command `drush php-eval "phpinfo()" | grep memory` reports:

[2] => --php-options=-d memory_limit="256M"

And after this `drush cc all` also fails when reaching 62M limit.

Comment: 61341696 bytes = ~61MB, which is nowhere near 1024MB. Remember that CLI and mod PHP/FPM are two different things, and are likely to have separate configuration files. Ask your host how/to increase the memory for the CLI version of PHP, rather than the one your website uses.

Comment: @Clive could you see the edit

Comment: Sorry for delay, not been at the computer. I think the answer is likely to be the same (the server is limiting you to 62MB per script for CLI), but maybe not. It's worth asking your hosting company to confirm if only to rule it out

Comment: This may be helpful - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/105170/18129 (at least it was for me..)